# add class on focus to form element

Tags: jquery

My goal is to add class "focus" to my form element that has the class .search-form on click. and remove it on blur.

here is my code:

```
$('search-form').on('blur', function(){
   $(this).removeClass('focus');
}).on('focus', function(){
  $(this).addClass('focus');
});
```

What am I doing wrong. It is not adding the class focus on click.

Html:

```
<form name="quick_find" action="http://localhost/gostwear6/advanced_search_result.php" method="get" class="search search-form group global-search  blur">
    <input type="text" name="keywords" value="1884" size="50" class="search-input" tabindex="1"  placeholder="Search"   />
    <button class="search-submit" type="submit"><span class="search-submission-text">Search</span></button>
    <input type="hidden" name="search_in_description" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="inc_subcat" value="1" />                             
</form>
```

Comment: Post your html code .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the `.` before the class selector :

```
$('.search-form')
```

Also, this is the form class, not the input. Try this :

```
$('.search-form input')
```

Comment: I tried that as well. And also the . before the .focus still does not work

Comment: @Sackling you dont need the dot before focus, only on the selector.

Comment: @Sackling and you are targeting the form, not the input.

Comment: ah ok.. Targeting the input was what I needed. I thought the form would be good enough?

Comment: @Sackling Unfortunatly no, you really have to be clear, but if you want to specify the form with pseudo class in css, you can use `.search-form :focus` (with a space).

Answer (score 0):

you can use css pseudo class `:focus`

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that was missing is the reference to the class.

```
$('.search-form').focus(...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/pC9q4/1/

Your code is perfect and it works fine! :)

Just tried your code, hey! You're having that as a submit button. Which forces the browser to load the page and submit the form. You can try to use

```
return false;
```

To see what happens when you click on the button.

After that change your code to access the button. Your code is a submit button so try to access it and change its class. Here is the code:

```
$('.search-form button').on('blur', function(){
   $(this).removeClass('focus');
}).on('focus', function(){
   $(this).addClass('focus');
}).on('click', function () {
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To target the form, use `focusout/focusin` events instead (which bubble):

```
$('.search-form').on('focusout', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('focus');
}).on('focusin', function () {
    $(this).addClass('focus');
});
```

As by default FORM cannot get focus, add attribute tabindex to FORM:

```
<form tabindex="-1" name="quick_find" ...>
```

For styling, use:

```
.search-form {outline:0}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SLar3/)

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
           $(".search-form form:first").blur(function(){
             $(this).removeClass("focus");
            }).focus(function(){
             $(this).addClass("focus");
            });
```